# Python Pipelines predict with transform receiving parameters

Tags: python, pipeline

I am looking at a case where I have a python Pipeline

```
pipeline=Pipeline([('scale',StandardScaler(),('custom_transformer',Ctran(),('model',LinearRegression())
```

The problem I have is that Ctran when fitting the pipeline it takes on(X,y,z) and when predicting with the pipeline Ctran takes on X and z, but y=None.

Now this would be no issue if I didn't require the z to be an argument when prediction, but since my custom transformer is dependent on input(z) external from X when fitting and predicting I am having issues with how to deal with the problem. I am able to fit the model by specifying:

custom_transformer__z=z, but when trying to predict I am getting this error message:

lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params) 467 468 Xt = X --> 469 for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False): 470 Xt = transform.transform(Xt) 471 return self.steps[-1][1].predict(Xt, **predict_params) TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'

how could I inherit from Pipeline and create a new Pipeline class that allows for the transformer to have arguments in the fit and predict face.

I am giving a silly example below as the full code I am not able to share. But the same issue is occurring here:

```
class Ctran(BaseEstimator,RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, model)
    self.model = model
    self.unq=[]
    self.clone_models=[]

    def fit(self,X,y,z):
        self.unq=np.unique(z)
        n=len(self.unq)
        self.clone_models= [base.clone(self.model) for _ in range(n)]


    

    for i,gr in enumerate(unq):
        index=z==gr
        if sum(index)>0:
            self.clone_models[i].fit(X[index],y[index])


def transform(self,X,y,z):
    
    y=np.empty((len(X),1))
    for i,gr in enumerate(self.unique):
        index =z==gr
        if sum(index)>0:
        y[index]=self.models[i].predict(X,y)
```

I want to use model(any sklearn model etc) to be fitted to subset of the dataset and then predict in the subset given groups identified.

This require that there are similar groups in the training vs prediction and that the order is the same, I might need to have a check that the order of the unique groups are the same in the fit and predict stage or else throw an error. But, the main problem is that at the end of this I am still left with the issue that the output from this transform method should be input to example a Linear regression(), in this simple example the output is a vector but it could be a matrix

Comment: share the code of Ctran()

Comment: @qaiser I have made a short example of similar problem